# How to take a Virtual Machine's Snapshot using Puppet when using VMWare

Tags: vmware, puppet

The answers i found lead me towards using [perl api for VMware orchestration.](http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/viperltoolkit/index.html)

or [VirtuallyGhetto](http://www.virtuallyghetto.com/p/vmware-vsphere-sdk-for-perl-vi-perl.html)

but cannot find puppet samples, where a user can get permissions to create a VM SnapShot, and also revert it, without having root access, or admin rights.

I also found [vmth](https://github.com/gregretkowski/vmth/) but VMTH currently only works in a QEMU+KVM environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a Exec resource and map it to the VMWare Api that allows you to create a VM Snapshot.

Note: Creating Snapshots are not usable anymore since you can create new VMs everytime.

Comment: the reason for snapshot is to save applications installed as well as any data that is in a particular state., so when we create NEW VM, those cannot be re-produced, if we can create VM's with certain data state, and installed applications, then certainly snapshots are not valid anymore.

Comment: I am nt sure if i understand your suggestion. How would i create an exec resource , is it using Puppet ? and what do you mean by a "map" and to WHICH VMWare API ?

Comment: If you are trying to create a VM snapshot from a puppet client using the VMWare API. The puppet client must have installed the client components for VCenter o ESXI.Then you must write a puppet class with resources that call the VMware API which can be the PowerCLI using Powershell or the basic API.

Comment: is it possible to give a user ONLY the permission to create and revert snapshot(s)